# Is there an equivalent of the Java <? extends ClassName> in C++?

Tags: java, c++, templates, inheritance

I am looking at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html and ask myself how it could be implemented in C++.

I have this small example to illustrate :

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual std::string type() const = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() {}
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual std::string type() const {
        return "I am a dog";
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual std::string type() const {
        return "I am a cat";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class AnimalFarm
{
};

void farmTest(const AnimalFarm<Animal *> &farm)
{        
    std::cout << "test farm";
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{          
    AnimalFarm<Dog *> dogFarm;
    AnimalFarm<Animal *> animalFarm;

    farmTest(animalFarm); // OK
    farmTest(dogFarm); // NOK compiler error as class AnimalFarm<Dog *> does not inherits from class AnimalFarm<Animal *>

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why it does not work in C++. In Java, the solution is to use the following construction :

```
List<? extends Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number>  numList = intList;  // OK. List<? extends Integer> is a subtype of List<? extends Number>
```

(given that `Integer` is a subclass of `Number` as pointed out in the example links).

Using :

```
template <typename U>
void farmTest(const AnimalFarm<U *> &farm);
```

might be solution but is there a better way to do that in C++ without loosing the fact that Cat or Dog inherits from Animal ( as `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes these kinds of problems can be untangled by having a non-template `class AnimalFarmBase {};` and have AnimalFarm inherit from that base class `template <typename T> class AnimalFarm : public AnimalFarmBase {};`.

Comment: `AnimalFarm` has no connection to `Animal`. What you seem to want is a way to define templated `farmTest` that only accepts `AnimalFram<T>` where  `T` is a subclass of class `Animal`. If so, one way is to templatize   `farmTest` where only `T`s is or is a subclass of `Animal`.

Comment: In C++, what's the problem you would solve with this? I know the problem it solves in Java - but IMO, that problem doesn't exist in C++. It's *good* that you can instantiate a template with anything that works, regardless of inheritance. The only problem with that is that it tends to produce terrible compilation error messages if a wrong type is used, but that will (some day in the future) solved by so-called concepts.

Comment: I have no specific C++ problem to solve with it. Though i am not a Java programmer, the question comes from Java and then i simply asked myself, how i would do this in C++.

Comment: The main goal of this sort of types in Java is that you can implement a method for each `AnimalFarm`, regardless of its type parameter, while still **ensuring** that the type parameter will be a subclass of `Animal`. In C++, this is not necessary: Templates (at this level) are rather some string replacement engine, and "if it works, it works - otherwise, it doesn't". (This has many drawbacks and limitations, beyond the scope of this comment). As Christian already mentioned: An std version of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm might eventually help...

Comment: @Marco13 - *"Templates (at this level) are rather some string replacement engine, and "if it works, it works - otherwise, it doesn't"."* That gross oversimplification is what Microsoft thought. That's why they recently had to actually [fix their template handling in MSVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/).

Comment: @StoryTeller The phrases *"at this level"* and *"rather"* should already indicate that this is an (over)simplification. The point is that for *this* particular pattern, the templates *can* be imagined to simply "create a copy of the code, once for each template argument", so that there is no need for wildcard types with upper bounds. The fact that the templating and type resolution mechanisms in C++ *in general* are beyond what an average programmer can understand is out of doubt. (OK, an average *Java* programmer, if you insist ;-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your end game is to form an *is-a* relationship between `AnimalFarm<Dog *>` and `AnimalFarm<Animal *>`, then a bit of template specialization with type traits can do that.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
class AnimalFarm // Primary template
{
};

template<typename T>
class AnimalFarm<T*,
  std::enable_if_t<
     !std::is_same<T, Animal>::value &&
      std::is_base_of<Animal, T>::value
  >
> // Specialization only instantiated when both conditions hold
  // Otherwise SFINAE
  : public AnimalFarm<Animal*>
{
};
```

Since `AnimalFarm<Animal*>` becomes a public base of `AnimalFarm<Dog*>`, the function parameter reference will bind to it. Though you should note that the corresponding hierarchy is flat, no matter how deep the `Animal` one goes.

You can check it out <kbd>[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43919851b562f901)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, i got the idea. However, how would you rewrite this conditional expression with `std::enable_if` instead of `std::enabled_if_t` ( ie using C++11  not C++14), i am not familiar with `type traits`

Comment: @Scab - You would replace `std::enabled_if_t<>` by `typename std::enabled_if<>::type`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is all of this really necessary to support the is-a relationship? The way I see it you can just write a template class and place a reference (or pointer) to the base class inside the template (e..g put Animal* instead T* ). This will even work for pre C++11.

Comment: @dsp_user - A reference is not enough. The objects lifetime must be tightly coupled. Even then, you'll have to take steps which will prevent `AnimalFarm<Animal*>` from requiring itself as any sort of base. And take steps to let the reference bind without explicitly calling something like `getBaseFarm()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had a situation where I did just that, which worked in my case (my base class was abstract (like in the OP's example), so I simply put a reference to Base to prevent instantiations from types that don't derive from Base. Ok, let's leave it there :)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalence may be a matter of exactly how we define equivalence (if not being opinion).

**If you want a runtime open container for any kind of animal...**

Sounds like a good opportunity for runtime polymorphism to solve.

A runtime polymorphic solution seems functionally similar if not equivalent (at least in my thinking) to what you're asking for. The best description I know of for the runtime polymorphism that I mean is [Sean Parent's "Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism"](https://youtu.be/QGcVXgEVMJg) talk.

Basically though the idea will hide the `Animal` inheritance hierarchy so from the container's perspective you can just use any container like `using AnimalFarm = std::vector<Animal>`. The details then go into the implementation of `Animal` like so:

```
class Animal {
    struct Concept {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual std::string type() const = 0;
        // add in more methods for any other properties your Animal "concept" has
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Model final: Concept {
        Model(T arg): data{std::move(arg)} {}            
        std::string type() const override {
            return get_type_name(data);
        }
        // override define whatever other methods the concept has

        T data; // stores the underlying type's data
    };

    std::shared_ptr<const Concept> m_self;

public:
    template <typename T>
    Animal(T v): m_self{std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::move(v))} {}

    // default or delete other constructors as needed.

    friend std::string get_type_name(const Animal& animal) {
        return animal.m_self->type();
    }
};
```

Now to have an `Animal` like a `Dog`, you just need free code like:

```
struct Dog {
};

inline std::string get_type_name(const Dog& dog) {
    return "Dog";
}
```

And usage (assuming at least C++11) is like...

```
using AnimalFarm = std::vector<Animal>;

int main() {
    auto theFarm = AnimalFarm{};
    theFarm.push_back(Dog{});
    for (const auto& e: theFarm) {
        std::cout << get_type_name(e) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that here, `Dog` is instantiated (`Dog{}`) and then implicitly gets turned into an `Animal` because of the way `Animal`'s initializing constructor is defined (both templated and non-`explicit`).

I just typed this code in by hand. So it's apt to have some mistakes in it. Hopefully it shows the jist of this answer in terms of the code though and I do hope it will help for your need.

**If, OTOH, you want the container to only have a specific kind of animal defined by the user of the conatiner...**

Then only add instances of the kind of animal to the above styled container.

**Or lastly, if you want compiler enforcement...**

Then do something like:

```
template <typename T>
using AnimalFarm = std::vector<T>;

void someCodeBlock() {
    AnimalFarm<Dog> dogFarm;
    dogFarm.push_back(Dog{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Design terminology

I second StoryTellers answer and suggestion to look at the relationship between types: The default relationship in C++ is **invariance** (i.e. no relationship), e.g. for function arguments, STL containers, and templates in general. An exception are smart pointers and function return types, which are all covariant.

#### Literature

If you google for the terms "variance", "covariance" and "contravariance", you will find several helpful articles.

Scott Meyers' Effective C++ and More Effective C++ touch the fundaments.

Sumant Tambe has a [detailed article in his C++ Truths blog about covariance and contravariance in C++, with a focus on the standard library](http://cpptruths.blogspot.de/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html). It contains a table listing which std library types have co(ntra)variance, where the only type offering both is `std::function<R *(T *)>` with covariant return types and contravariant arguments. Furthermore, it shows various approaches to these relationships.

#### Best practice

In specification, design and formal verification, a quasi-standard is invariant genericity and return types and arguments as in `std::function<R *(T *)>`. However, there are other opinions, e.g. Betrand Meyers book [Object-Oriented Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554) and his language [Eiffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)) promoting covariant function arguments.

For C++, I believe invariant genericity is most suitable: Because of total template specialization, covariance makes no sense: you can totally specialize `AnimalFarm<Cat>`, so that it definitely does not fulfill the is-a relationship to `AnimalFarm<Animal>`. Due to static duck typing, the default invariance in C++ does not cause strong restrictions.